# Swift and Firebase | How precise is the .timestamp(), can I use it as an identification?

Tags: swift, firebase, timestamp

I am making a quiz game for iOS and I need a way to identify which game is which. Can I use the .timestamp() or is there a chance that two games could end up with the same timestamp value?

Comment: If you have a limited amount of users this will be no issue. But when you have millions of users you will have collisions. Some caution is needed when working with timestamps across front-end / back-end and across multiple front-end timezones. If you do not make sure every device is creating timestamps in UTC 00, you will have weird results.

Comment: A better way to create identifiers is to generate UUID's [Q/A on UUID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428250/generate-uuid-in-xcode-swift)

Comment: @RMenke that seems to be a good way to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to create identifiers, as suggested by @RMenke is to use `NSUIID().UUIDString`...

**For example**

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
print(uuid)
```